# Permissions on shared folder with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharing

I need to set the permissions for "**Everyone**" to **Change** and **Read** with PowerShell on a shared folder. I don't know how to do it, can you help me?

- I'm running windows server 2008

[image]

The following code works fine on Windows Server 2012. I need to run it on Windows Server 2008:

```
[WMICLASS]"Win32_Share"|%{$_.Create($path,$sharefoldername,0)} | Out-Null
    Grant-SmbShareAccess -name $sharefoldername -CimSession $Server -AccountName Everyone -AccessRight Change –Force | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working answer that I found is this:

```
        #Username/Group to give permissions to
        $trustee = ([wmiclass]'Win32_trustee').psbase.CreateInstance()
        $trustee.Domain = $null
        $trustee.Name = "Everyone"

        #Accessmask values
        #$fullcontrol = 2032127
        $change = 1245631
        #$read = 1179785

        #Create access-list
        $ace = ([wmiclass]'Win32_ACE').psbase.CreateInstance()
        $ace.AccessMask = $change
        $ace.AceFlags = 3
        $ace.AceType = 0
        $ace.Trustee = $trustee

        #Securitydescriptor containting access
        $sd = ([wmiclass]'Win32_SecurityDescriptor').psbase.CreateInstance()
        $sd.ControlFlags = 4
        $sd.DACL = $ace
        $sd.group = $trustee
        $sd.owner = $trustee


        $share = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -List -ComputerName $server
        $share.create($advsharing, $sharefoldername, 0, "16777216", "Description"", $sd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SmbShare cmdlets:

```
Import-Module SmbShare
Get-Command -Noun Smb*
```

for an existing share you can use Grand-SmbShareAccess, you can use Get-Help to get some examples how it is used.

```
Get-Help Grant-SmbShareAccess -Examples
```

Comment: On Windows Server 2008? Do I have to upgrade to PowerShell 3?